# Classification problem: Choosing medication to prevent side effects based on patient characteristics

Tags: machine-learning, descriptive-statistics, scikit-learn

I need your help to solve a classification problem. Typically, we have independent variables and we try to predict a target variable. I have a different type of problem to solve.

In my case, let's take a simple example. Suppose I have a database with 6 variables: "white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender," "medication," and "side_effects."

"Medication" contains 0 and 1 for the type of medication, and "side_effects" contains 0 and 1 for no side effects or yes.

I would like to create a classification model that examines the patient's characteristics ("white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender") and provides the correct value of "medication" such that "side_effects" = 0.

I'm not sure if there are tools available for this kind of problem, and I haven't found much information online. ChatGPT hasn't been very helpful either.

The solution I've tried, though I'm not sure if it's valid, is as follows:

I divided my database into two parts: "side_effects" = 0 and "side_effects" = 1. I created two random forest models to predict "medication."

The first model, where the database is "side_effects" = 0, predicts either medication 0 or 1. This would mean that this medication should be chosen to avoid side effects. The second model, where the database is "side_effects" = 1, predicts either medication 0 or 1. This would imply that this medication causes side effects.

Then, I added the predict_proba from the first model to the smaller one from the second model to choose the correct medication.

Here is a part of my code:

```
# first model
NoSide_df = df[df['side_effect'] == 0]
# Séparation des caractéristiques (X) et de la variable cible (y)
X = NoSide_df[["white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender"]]
y = NoSide_df['medication']  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
modelNoSide = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
modelNoSide.fit(X_train, y_train)

# second model
Side_df = df[df['side_effect'] == 1]
# Séparation des caractéristiques (X) et de la variable cible (y)
X = Side_df[["white_blood_cells," "age," "weight," "gender"]]
y = Side_df['medication']  
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
modelNoSide = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=42)
modelSide.fit(X_train, y_train)

# prediction for first model
prediction_medicamentNoside = modelNoSide.predict(new_data)
proba_prediction_medicamentNoside = modelNoSide.predict_proba(new_data)
probability_class_NOSide0 = proba_prediction_medicamentNoside[0, 0]  
probability_class_NoSide1 = proba_prediction_medicamentNoside[0, 1]
# prediction for second model
prediction_medicamentSide = modelSide.predict(new_data)
proba_prediction_medicamentSide = modelSide.predict_proba(new_data)
probability_class_Side0 = proba_prediction_medicamentSide[0, 0] 
probability_class_Side1 = proba_prediction_medicamentSide[0, 1]  

#prediction combined
# Probabilités maximales des deux modèles
max_probability_modelNoSide = max(probability_class_NOSide0, probability_class_NoSide1)
min_probability_modelSide = min(probability_class_Side0, probability_class_Side1)

# Moyenne des probabilités maximales
average_max_probability = (max_probability_modelNoSide + min_probability_modelSide) / 2.0

if probability_class_NOSide0 > probability_class_NoSide1:
    # Affichage de la moyenne des probabilités maximales
    print("medicament = 0 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", average_max_probability,"\n",
         "medicament = 1 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", 1-average_max_probability,)
else: 
    print("medicament = 1 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", average_max_probability,"\n",
         "medicament = 0 n'a pas d'effet indesirbale pour ce groupe ", 1-average_max_probability,)
```

Could you please help me with this approach or suggest a better way to solve this problem? Thanks!